# Windows 10 Update messed up my computer

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I was running Windows 7, then I got this popup asking me if I wanted to install Windows 10 now or later. I selected later. Then I had to select a date and time for the installation to happen. I selected a date 3 days in the future.
I left my computer for a while. When I got back, there was a Windows 10 desktop...
After a while, my computer went into stand-by mode and it wouldn't come out of it, so I had to press the restart button on the front of my computer.

My system is all messed up. Many things don't work:
I don't have a Start Menu (when I click the Start button, nothing happens).
Even Task Manager won't run. (I get an error saying "The extended attributes are inconsistent." apparently this is an issue with sound settings, but that won't open either.)

I want to rollback my system to Windows 7, but there's no way the Settings window will show up. I found something that has to do with a missing Settings window called "Emerging Issue 67758", but when I download the [fix](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-settings-app-does-not-launch) and try to run it, I get an error: "An unexpected error has occurred. The troubleshooting wizard can't continue."

When I go to Control Panel -> Recovery, there's an option: "If you're having problems with your PC, go to settings and try resetting it", but when I click that, I get another error: "Class not registered"

Is there a way to get back my Windows 7, besides reinstalling from disk and starting over? (The windows.old folder is still there)

Comment: What fix did you download specifically?  It sounds like when you forced the machine to reboot, you prevented any chance of being able to roll back to Windows 7, I suggest you cut your loses.

Comment: @Ramhound It's described here: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-settings-app-does-not-launch It was in stand-by mode and wasn't responding to anything, so rebooting was the only thing I could do.

Comment: Update your question.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/220723/how-to-uninstall-windows-10-and-downgrade-to-windows-7-or-8.1/

Answer (score -1):

You might try following these steps to remove Windows 10. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_7-windows_install/how-to-uninstall-windows-10-and-restore-windows-7/839c5f7d-8204-4639-85b0-044fa4539984

Comment: That is what I want to do: open the Settings windows and click 'rollback'. But I don't have a Settings window. I don't have a start menu. I can't restart my computer except for the button on the computer case itself. Many things don't work. Either I get an error or nothing happens at all. How the heck do I do this?